# What does it mean "they had going in to the project" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Mind mapping builds a common mind about current reality and thus decreases
people's allegiance to the solutions they had going in to the project.
Thanks

Comment: Solutions they had when they started on the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going into the project (meaning near the start of it) people had some solutions. They had allegiance to those solutions ( meaning they believed and were attached to them). Mind mapping reduced that level of allegiance.( Presumably this made it easier for agreement to be reached on a single solution).